# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '5' of undefined

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток. Господа, я в отчаянии. Есть:

```
var subparts=[
    [0,'Раздел_1',10,0],
    [1,'Раздел_2',10,1],
    [2,'Раздел_3',10,2],
    ...
    ];

var items=[
    [0,'Пункт_1','параметр_1','параметр_2',10,0],
    [1,'Пункт_2','параметр_1','параметр_2',10,1],
    [2,'Пункт_3','параметр_1','параметр_2',10,2],
    ...
    ];

for (var k =0, subpart_id, i=0; k < subparts.length; k++) {
  console.log(subparts[k][1]);
  for (; k == items[i][5]; i++) {
    console.log('  '+items[i][1]);
  }
}
```

Как я хочу — обход по массиву, если subparts содержит какие-то элементы из items, они перечисляются ниже. Что получается — так и получается, но консоль почему-то выдает «Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '5' of undefined» (и в этом: **fire** в *jquery-1.8.3.js:974*, **self.fireWith** в *jquery-1.8.3.js:1084*, **jQuery.extend.ready** в *jquery-1.8.3.js:406*, **DOMContentLoaded** в *jquery-1.8.3.js:83*). Что это может значить?

Comment: вы бы вместо массивов использовали именованные поля, было бы читабельнее.

Comment: Да, но как-то так уже начал, сейчас уже не стану переделывать. Может в новой версии.  
И это же не может влиять на появление ошибки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понял вообще условие второго цикла. Вот нормальное сравнение (только подставьте индексы сравниваемых элементов массива правильные):

```
var subparts=[
    [0,'Раздел_1',10,0],
    [1,'Раздел_2',10,1],
    [2,'Раздел_3',10,2]
];

var items=[
    [0,'Пункт_1','параметр_1','параметр_2',10,0],
    [1,'Пункт_2','параметр_1','параметр_2',10,1],
    [2,'Пункт_3','параметр_1','параметр_2',10,2]
];

for (var k =0, subpart_id; k < subparts.length; k++) {
   console.log(subparts[k][1]);
   for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
      if (items[i][5]==subparts[k][0]) console.log('  '+items[i][1]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

В вашем коде `i` только возрастает на каждой итерации по `k`, и никогда не сбрасывается. Немудрено, что оно в конце-концов становится больше количества элементов в `items`, после чего `items[i]` -- это undefined, а `items[i][5]` выбросит исключение.

Не отчаивайтесь, просто обнуляйте `i` в начале каждой итерации по `k`.

Comment: И как, извините, её (i) «сбросить»? Точнее где?